# PHP preg_replace to remove MS Office style html comments

Tags: php, html, comments, preg-replace

Im looking for a way to remove MS Office style html comments, and everything in between. These are of the form:

`<!--[if gte mso 10]>`

blablabla
blablabla

`<![endif]-->`

or

`<!--[if gte mso 9]>`

blablabla
blablabla

`<![endif]-->`

The problem i'm encountering is that I do not want to remove ALL comments from the html. Only these MSO style comments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
preg_replace('/<!--\s*\[if[^\]]*]>.*?<!\[endif\]-->/i', '', $string);
```

it will remove all `<!--[if ...]>....<![endif]-->` comments

Comment: `<!-- [if !mso]>` this with white space before `[`doesnt match

Comment: @l2aelba added `\s*` after `<!--`