# What are smart tags and how do I remove them from html?

Tags: php, html, parsing, smart-tags

So I am still working on this parser. Today I found a document with the tag `<st1:place w:st="on">` Google tells me it is a Microsoft Office Smart Tag.

I would like to get rid of these things but I cannot find a list of what they are or how many of them there are?

If they all follow the `<...:...>` pattern it would be easy to remove with regex.

The document has no doctype and a .jsp extention, but all the content is between two `<html>` tags, and however non-standard the beast is, I still need to parse it.

OK it is actually not a big issue but it throws off my formatting & bugs me.

Comment: See ths: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3801803/180136

Comment: Even Jeff Atwood has covered this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/cleaning-words-nasty-html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp should do the trick:

```
/<[:alnum:]+:[\s\S]*>/
```

It will trigger on any tag that opens with < followed by an alphanumeric pattern followed by a ':' colon.

Alternatively:

```
/<\s*[:alnum:]+:[\s\S]*>/
```

Would allow looser formatter of the tag (space between the opening < and the namespace)

Answer (score -1):

We wanted to remove the `<w:smartTag>` and what is listed below is helped us.

```
/<w:smartTag[^>]*>/
```